# Vagrant error while starting vm with host only network

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, 64-bit, vagrant

I have set host only networking in my vagrant vm using the command

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

But after setting that everytime I try to start `vagrant up` the vm it fails miserably emitting the error log below

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...                                                                                                                         
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...                                                                                                                            
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...                                                                                                                                       
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...                                                                                                                         
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant                                                                                                              
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.                                                                                                                  

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]                                                                                                                                                   

Stderr: 0%...                                                                                                                                                                       
Progress state: E_INVALIDARG                                                                                                                                                        
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter                                                                                                                       
VBoxManage.exe: error: Assertion failed: [!aGuid.isValid()] at 'D:\tinderbox\win-4.3\src\VBox\Main\src-server\HostNetworkInterfaceImpl.cpp' (74) in long __cdecl HostNetworkInterface::init(class com::Bstr,class com::Bstr,class com::Guid,enum __MIDL___MIDL_itf_VirtualBox_0000_0000_0034).                                                                          
VBoxManage.exe: error: Please contact the product vendor!                                                                                                                           
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterface, interface IHostNetworkInterface                                                           
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "int __cdecl handleCreate(struct HandlerArg *,int,int *)" at line 66 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

Below is my vagrant file content -

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise64"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the answer for anyone who is facing a similar issue. This [issue ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12182) clearly explains this as a bug in VirtualBox itself. Please follow this link for more information. This is supposed to only happen on a [64-bit](/questions/tagged/64-bit) machines. Please download this [test build](http://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VirtualBox-4.3.3-90468-Win.exe) where they have fixed the issue, though this has not yet arrived on the stable release.